# Is PHP actually ported to AmigaOS?

Tags: script, php, amiga, php-cli

I have long had the thought about what it would be like to have PHP running on an Amiga (I mean a real one), and have tried to search and ask about this.

It's ambiguous as to whether or not it really exists.

I *have* found this: https://amigaos.net/software/77/aamp-apache-mysql-php

Does this weird, unofficial "package" really mean that PHP is properly ported to AmigaOS? Does it actually let you run PHP scripts and access the file system with its non-standard paths, with correct values for `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, `PHP_EOL`, etc.? It even claims to support "extensions".

The weirdest part is that PHP isn't even the "main thing" about that package; it's simply mentioned as one of the components of what is apparently an all-in-one Apache + MySQL + PHP solution for the Amiga.

Does that thing have a PHP CLI binary to run scripts on the command line? How well can it possibly run? I have so many questions, but no Amiga to try it on.

It seems as if it was last updated in 2006, and it mentions PHP 5, so it's not exactly PHP 8.2, but still makes me very curious and wondering how feasible it would be to run modern PHP on an Amiga. I like the idea to be able to use the same code as I do on my modern Linux machine but to instead script an Amiga (and host web tools on it).

I took a look inside `aamp.lha`, but it didn't make much sense to me. The "bin" dir just talks about "putting binaries here", which is weird since that is what that package is supposed to provide...

Secondary source for some of the details (in German): https://schwan-clan.de/index.php?lang=de&fr0=AmigaFrameNav.php%3Flang%3Dde%26sub%3D0&fr1=amiga%2FSoftware.php%3Flang%3Dde

Is PHP actually ported to AmigaOS, through this package or something better?

Comment: As far as I can see, Amiga paths don't seem too different from Windows-style paths... Consider that modern Perl runs on OpenVMS, with its _even more_ non-standard paths (`dev:[dir.subdir.subdir]path.ext;ver`), not to mention record-oriented files...

Answer (score 2):

http://aminet.net/package/comm/www/thttpd2.21b_working_php

A 4.x version, not the latest, but a PHP ;-)

And there are some others; http://aminet.net/search?query=PHP